# Why are cats so cute?

Tags: cats

What is it about cats that makes them so irresistibly cute?

My cat is very cute. My previous cats have all been cute too. Other cats I see are cute. Dogs are also cute, of course, but their cuteness should be addressed in a separate question.

My cat is cute for all the normal reasons, but he is also extra cute because he is so vocal and has a beautiful, sing-songy meow. He sounds angelic. He's my 5th lifetime cat (I've always had cats since childhood and most overlapped) and I've never heard anything like it.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the larger questions in life can not be answered,Why we love cats is one of those questions.

Some people think toxoplasmosis an brain controlling amoeba that cats carry plays a role in our love of cats,the truth is we do not know.

In the middle ages people and cats where killed as a result of their love of cats and the cats love of people,people that loved cats was seen as whitches and got killed,We still love cats today so i have to say it must be true love we experience and the cats must truly love us.

I got my first cat when i was two years old and i have had cats for my entire life i am 54years old now and i still wonder why do i love cats and why do cats love me,I do not have the answer yet.

Here is a link to one theory https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/intimacy-path-toward-spirituality/201507/if-you-love-cats-may-be-why to why we love cats.

here is an other link https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-love-cats-so-much you can follow the links on the page for some more information.

I do not think we will ever find an answer to your question,But keep on looking :)